# How to save money on currency conversion

Tags: currency, fees, usd-us-dollar, cad-canadian-dollar

I do business with a few companies in the United States, and as such, get paid in US currency for my services. I have a US account with my bank, but anytime that I make withdrawals from this account, the amount taken for conversion fees is quite painful (to give an example, the dollar was 1 = 1.09 on Wednesday, I got 1 = 1.05 for my transfer to my chequeing account).

So my question is, is there a way to get a conversation rate that is closer to what is actually advertised and/or avoid such fees at all?

Comment: "closer to what is actually advertised" - advertised by *whom*?

Comment: How large are the amounts that you want to convert?

Comment: @littleadv I usually use xe.com to get prices for currency conversion, seems to be on par to what you find in the business section

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt roughly five grand at one time.

Comment: How are you making the withdrawals?

Comment: @littleadv currently account transfer within the bank from one to another.

Comment: That would, in my experience, be one of the cheapest options. But do shop around with different banks. May be wiring money from one bank to another may be cheaper, depending on the banks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert more than a few thousand dollars, one [somewhat complex method](http://www.financialwisdomforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=198) is to have two investment accounts at a discount broker that operations both in Canada and the USA, then buy securities for USD on a US exchange, have your broker move them to the Canadian account, then sell them on a Canadian exchange for CAD.

This will, of course, incur trading fees, but they should be lower than most currency conversion fees if you convert more than a few thousand dollars, because trading fees typically have a very small percentage component.

[Using a currency ETF](http://www.canadiancapitalist.com/a-foolproof-method-to-convert-canadian-dollars-into-us-dollars/) as the security to buy/sell can eliminate the market risk.

In any case, it may take up to a week for the trades and transfer to settle.