# What is an effective way to convert large sums of US based investments to foreign currencies?

Tags: united-states, currency, foreign-exchange

Considering the option of one day retiring to a different country (probably an EU country). I've done a good job saving for retirement in IRA/Roth/401K accounts primarily held in mutual funds and American stocks.

What has recently occurred to me is that if I were to move to a country, for example on the euro, I'd be paying a massive amount of money to convert to the local currency. It is one thing to do this for a vacation, but my retirement account will likely exceed 7 figures by the time I am ready to retire. Even at a 1% conversion that is a helluva a lot of money to come right off the top.

Is there some better approach for moving large sums of money to a foreign currency. For example, is there a way to sell NYSE/NASDAQ investments held through a brokerage for foreign currency? Or maybe there are currency exchanges that offer discounted conversion rates for large transactions? Maybe something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stock, bond or ETF is basically a commodity. Where you bought it does not really matter, and it has a value in USD only inasmuch as there is a current market price quoted at an American exchange. But nothing prevents you from turning around and selling it on a European exchange where it is also listed for an equivalent amount of EUR (arbitrage activities of investment banks ensure that the price *will* be equivalent in regard to the current exchange rate). In fact, this can be used as a cheap form of [currency conversion](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30457/how-to-save-money-on-currency-conversion/30467#30467). For blue chips at least this is trivial; exotic securities might not be listed in Europe.

All you need is a broker who allows you to trade on European exchanges and hold an account denominated in EUR. If necessary, transfer your securities to a broker who does, which should not cost more than a nominal fee.

Mutual funds are a different beast though; it might be possible to sell shares on an exchange anyway, or sell them back to the issuer for EUR. It depends.

In any case, however, transferring 7 figure sums internationally can trigger all kinds of tax events and money laundering investigations. You *really* need to hire a financial advisor who has international investment experience for this kind of thing, not ask a web forum!

Comment: In truth I probably wouldn't transfer it all at once, but withdraw it as I need it to live on in retirement. Just trying to figure out how not to get eaten up on fees while doing so as I probably would if I cashed in my investments then did some form of currency exchange.